# Is there a way to add a numerical value to a variable in lua in a for loop?

Tags: lua

I made this program:

```
a = math.random(0, 9) - 0 -- In this stage, if the result equals zero, that means it's a match
b = math.random(0, 9) - 1
c = math.random(0, 9) - 2
d = math.random(0, 9) - 3
e = math.random(0, 9) - 4
f = math.random(0, 9) - 5
g = math.random(0, 9) - 6
h = math.random(0, 9) - 7
i = math.random(0, 9) - 8
j = math.random(0, 9) - 9

print("Enter the number of trials you want to simulate.") -- This is where I decide how many trials I want to do

var = io.read()

a_ = 0 -- This is where I hope to keep the number of "a" matches, number of "b" matches, etc. The frequency
b_ = 0
c_ = 0
d_ = 0
e_ = 0
f_ = 0
g_ = 0
h_ = 0
i_ = 0
j_ = 0

for k = 1, var do -- One loop is a trial

    print("Trail #"..k)

    if a == 0 then
        print("a = match")
    elseif a ~= 0 then
        print("a = not a match")
    end

    if b == 0 then
        print("b = match")
    elseif b ~= 0 then
        print("b = not a match")
    end

    if c == 0 then
        print("c = match")
    elseif c ~= 0 then
        print("c = not a match")
    end

    if d == 0 then
        print("d = match")
    elseif d ~= 0 then
        print("d = not a match")
    end

    if e == 0 then
        print("e = match")
    elseif e ~= 0 then
        print("e = not a match")
    end

    if f == 0 then
        print("f = match")
    elseif f ~= 0 then
        print("f = not a match")
    end

    if g == 0 then
        print("g = match")
    elseif g ~= 0 then
        print("g = not a match")
    end

    if h == 0 then
        print("h = match")
    elseif h ~= 0 then
        print("h = not a match")
    end

    if i == 0 then
        print("i = match")
    elseif i ~= 0 then
        print("i = not a match")
    end

    if j == 0 then
        print("j = match")
    elseif j ~= 0 then
        print("j = not a match")
    end

end

while true do --This is just to keep the window open after the program is done so that I can observe the data, you can ignore this
end
```

As you can see, I tried to add one to a_, b_ and c_ every time it returns a result of zero, but it doesn't work, it there a way to do this?
The reason I want to do this is for an AP stats class I'm taking, and this will make it a lot easier to do. I'm just doing a_, b_, c_ for now, once I solve this issue, I'll do all of them. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Please provide a simplified version of your code, yours is long and rather unorganized.

Comment: I don't know how to simplify it, sorry. I'm not very good at Lua and this is the best I can do. Any tips on simplifying?

Comment: I added notes if that helps with what my goal is

Comment: Use `io.read()` to keep the window open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the simulation to run 'var' times, try this:

```
math.randomseed(os.time())

local matchStorage = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
local randomNums = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

local function runSimulation(numTrial)
    print("\nRunning trial #: " .. numTrial)

    for index, value in pairs(randomNums) do
        local variable = math.random(0, 9)
        randomNums[index] = variable
    end

    for index, value in pairs(randomNums) do
        if randomNums[index] == 0 then
            matchStorage[index] = matchStorage[index] + 1
            print("index " .. index .. " is a match.")
        else
            print("index " .. index .. " is not a match.")
        end
    end
end

do
    print("Enter the number of trials")
    numTrials = io.read()

    for index = 1, numTrials do
        runSimulation(index)
    end

    print("\nRESULTS:\n")

    for index, value in pairs(matchStorage) do
        print("index " .. index .. " frequency: " .. value)
    end
end
```

The number of times that one of the following 'randomNum' values contain a 0 will be stored in its corresponding 'matchStorage' index.

Comment: OMG Thanks so much for the help, I was able to do 100,000 trials. This helped SOOO much. I couldn't thank you enough for basiaclly re-writting the entire program for me. Not the kind of frequency I was looking for, but I'll fix, thx again